# Calendar Event add wrong time issue

Tags: ios, swift, ekevent, ekeventstore, ekeventkit

I am working on calendar application.

I am trying to add add new event in default iPhone calendar.In this case successfully added event,but start time always set 5.30 PM in default iPhone calendar how to solve this issue

Attached below piece of code,

```
 let event = EKEvent(eventStore: store)
 event.title = "calendar Name"
 event.startDate = startDate //2016-05-19 00:00:00 +0000
 event.endDate = endDate // 2016-05-19 23:59:59 +0000
 event.calendar = store.defaultCalendarForNewEvents
 do {

    try store.saveEvent(event, span: .ThisEvent, commit: true)

  } catch {

  }
```

Comment: How do you get startDate and endDate ? Please do mention full info for better understanding

Comment: let gregorian = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
        gregorian?.timeZone =  NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)
        let components = gregorian?.components([.Year,.Month,.Day], fromDate:currentDate)
        components?.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)
        components?.hour = 00
        components?.second = 00
        components?.minute = 00
        let beggingOfDay = gregorian?.dateFromComponents(components!)

Comment: i don't catch what you are doing? What you want to do? Which date you want and in which timezone?

Comment: get current date with time 00.00.0

Comment: but iPhone calendar event creating time always 5.30 how to solve this time issue

Comment: set event start date current date with 2016-05-19 00:00:00 +0000 format but native calendar app start time 5.30 Pm

Comment: StartDate is printing like : 2016-05-19 00:00:00 +0000 or not?

Comment: This is event.startDate print log 2016-05-19 00:00:00 +0000

Comment: Are you getting this format now thats what i am asking?

Comment: startDate set perfect but iPhone calendar show correct date but time only differ

Comment: No, its right. Just set locale like : `components?.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")` set identifier as your need

Comment: try this but same issue return event date start from particular day 5.30AM

Comment: Seems like your device timezone is set to IST

If so, displaying 5.30 is the expected behaviour. Because when saving you are saving in GMT; notice the +0000 in the time.

Comment: An event starting at 00.00 in GMT will start at 5.30 in IST

Comment: set device timezone to GMT and check it once.

Comment: Also, looks like you want to set an event for entire day.

So just set event.allDay = YES;

Comment: if allday set true eventEndDate mandatory?

Comment: It is not mandatory. I hope the above suggestion solved your problem?

Comment: if allday set true default take start time 12.00Am beginning of day is true?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your device timezone is set to IST.

Hence, 5.30 AM displayed in your device’s calendar is the expected behaviour. Because when saving the start time; you are saving it in GMT; notice the +0000 in the time.

If you want to save the event as an all day event,
Simply set

```
event.allDay = YES
```